# Can I create and use my own license or do I need to publish it somewhere?

Tags: licensing, license-creation, crayon-licenses

I have created a license for my apps:

> This computer program is licensed under Illuze License v1.0.0 or later.
>
> Illuze License
>   v1.0.0 [3rdDec2015]
>   -Rahul2001.com
>   It's simple:
>
> -You are free to use this application in any manner as long as you aren't, in any way (directly or indirectly), hurting a living being.
>
> -You are free to distribute this in any manner or as many times as you like.
>
> -You are free to use the source code (if provided) in any manner but must give credit to the original source(s) or author(s).
>
> -You are NOT allowed to sell this app.
>
> -You are NOT allowed to bundle it with anything that may count as:
>    (i)Malware, (ii)Adware, (iii)Spyware or an otherwise undesirable application.
>
> -You are not allowed to distribute compromised versions of this app.
>
> -Any modified version of this application must also be licensed under the Illuze license.
>
> -Any application which uses this application completely, or in part, must also be licensed under the Illuze license.
>
> -The author is NOT responsible for what you do.
>
> -No warranties/guarantees are provided with this application.

Do I need to publish or register it anywhere for it to count as a proper license?

Also, can anyone see any potential issues with this? I only plan to use this because other licenses are *too* long for my liking and let's be honest, most people don't even read them... Creative Commons is awesome but doesn't suit my needs and requirements...

Comment: Your license isn't Free Software, or Open Source, and it's twice as long as many licenses which are!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Please please please don't use that license.**

To answer your main question, no, you don't need to register a license for it to "count". You just include it with the software it's licensing.

To answer "are there any potential problems": yes there are.

> - You are not allowed to distribute compromised versions of this app.

Define "compromised".

> - You are NOT allowed to bundle it with anything that may count as: (i)Malware, (ii)Adware, (iii)Spyware or an otherwise undesirable application.

Bundle what? This is legal stuff, be specific. Bundle.. the pig? Bundle... the software? Specify.

Additionally, define (i) malware, (ii) adware, (iii) spyware, and (iv) undesirable.

> - You are free to distribute this in any manner
>
> (...)
>
> - You are NOT allowed to sell this app.

Contradiction in terms. "Any manner" implies I *can* sell it; then you tell me I can't. Legal ambiguity is *bad*.

Also, again, "distribute this". What's *this*?

---

I'll stop picking your license apart now. Don't feel too bad about it - lots of people try to write their own licenses, and unless it's done with a lawyer, almost all of those fail. Use a license that's been professionally vetted, *please*.

Answer (score 8):

**Do not create your own license**. It will probably miss many of the legal subtleties, and end up either allowing much more than you want or much less. It will be incompatible with other licenses, leaving your work as an isolated island, useless to anybody else and abandoned.

Search for "choose open source license" (one of the first hits is 
http://choosealicense.com). Also consider David A. Wheeler's [essay](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/gpl-compatible.html) on open source licenses.

Answer (score 5):

**Theoretically** everyone is allowed to create their own license. But it is **highly recommended to contact a lawyer**, because one can make much things wrong.

But you don't need to register your license anywhere. But it has to be published with the product (for example as a *LICENSE.txt* file)